# logging values from arduino to postgres db

Tags: python, database, postgresql, arduino

I have a temperature sensor ([LM35][1]) interfaced with an Arduino board and my [sketch][2] is able to log values to the serial port, say `/dev/ttyACM0` in Ubuntu, and I was able to install pySerial and log the temperature values into a file... I used the command

```
python -m serial.tools.miniterm /dev/ttyACM0 >> templogger.csv
```

So it will log values like

```
27
28
27
```

into the templogger.csv file.

Instead of logging into the csv file Can I log these values directily to a postresql database say Db1 with username 'abc' and password 'xyz'. Is it possible through python, Can you please help by providing the required script

Comment: Yes, you can! Look at the wonderful Python database API documentation and get started. Once you have a specific question feel free to come back here and show us your code and problem.

Answer (score 1):

Start with [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/), which implements the Python database API.

You'll probably want to start with simple individual `INSERT`s, but later on you'll be able to batch work into transactions or use `COPY` to improve write performance.

In general, it's better to post questions for more specific problems than this. See [Stack Overflow Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help). If you're stuck on something it's fine to ask for help, but it's preferable that you try to figure it out first. You'll get better results if your questions are more like: "I've tried to use psycopg2 to connect my Python program to PostgreSQL so I can write sensor logging to the database, but when I `INSERT` a row I get `[exact error text here]`. Searching for the error message hasn't helped me, so I'm a bit stuck."

In other words, try it, and if you get stuck, ask. I'd normally just close-vote a question like this as "too localized" or "not a real question", which would give you an automatic link to the question writing guide, but you're new here and you've made an effort to write a decent question so I'm trying to explain in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of logging into the csv file Can I log these values directily to a postresql database say Db1 with username 'abc' and password 'xyz'. Is it possible through python, Can you please help by providing the required script?

Have a good look at a [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html) [tutorial](http://www.rmunn.com/sqlalchemy-tutorial/tutorial.html), and try to make a code that can works for you. Basically, you can extrapolate from the example:

```
from serial import Serial
from sqlalchemy import *

class Temperature(object):
    pass

class TemperatureStore:
    def __init__(self, dburl):
        self.db = create_engine('postgresql://%s' % dburl)
        self.db.echo = True
        metadata = BoundMetaData(db)
        temperatures = Table('temperatures', metadata, autoload=True)
        temperaturemapper = mapper(Temperature, temperatures)
        self.session = create_session()

    def push_temperature(self, temp):
        temp = Temperature()
        temp.value = temp
        session.save(temp)

def main():
    ser = Serial(port='/dev/ttyXXX', baudrate=115200)
    tempstore = TemperatureStore('abc:xyz@localhost:5432/Db1')
    while True:
        tempstore.push_temperature(ser.read())
```

This is just an example that may or may not work (I did not test it, just wrote it in 5 minutes), so you'd better get some inspiration from that, and try to work out your own!